# Reference specific class from its generic base class

Tags: c#

When working with generics if I have for example a class:

```
class Foo<T> where T:Cheese
{
}
```

and then 2 derived classes

```
class FooDerivedBlue:Foo<BlueCheese>
{
}

class FooDerivedWhite:Foo<WhiteCheese>
{
}
```

where `BlueChesse` and `WhiteCheese` inherit from `chesse`.

Now there is another class, that will conditionally use `FooDerivedBlue` or `FooDerivedWhite`.

The class should have a property like

```
public Foo<Cheese> Foo {get;set;}
```

so I can set it to the `FooDerivedXXX` I need at runtime.

When doing this an trying to set `Foo=new FooDerivedWhite()` the compiler will complain, since `FooDerivedWhite` cant be converted to `Foo<cheese>`.

**A more practical example:**

If I have a

- `ArticleRepository<T>`
- `AssemblyArticleRepository:ArticleRepository<AssemblyArticle>`
- `ProductionArticleRepository:ArticleRepository<ProductionArticle>`.
- `ProductionArticle` and `AssemblyArticle` inherit from `Article`.

Both specific repositories inherit from ArticleRepository  and have a lot of common logic. There are certain parts I need only access to the logic they shared (for example adding a new item or deleting it) and in order to avoid duplicate code, I want to instantiate the proper repo and pass it.

For example, I could have an ArticleService, which I pass a type and it instantiates the right repository. Instead, I would need to have a service for each Article type. (??- with my actual knowledge)

Which is the way to solve it in .NET? Or maybe I am facing the problem/writing my code in a wrong way?

**Update** Here a gist with the concrete problem:
https://gist.github.com/rgomez90/17ec21a1a371be6d78a53a4072938f7f

Comment: You might be able to define an interface `IFoo<out T> where T : class` depending on the operations you need to support. What does the rest of the `Foo<T>` class look like?

Comment: The problem is if some method uses T as a parameter I can't do that sofaik...

Comment: Can't do what? `FooDerivedWhite` would be a subtype of `IFoo<Cheese>` for example, which would allow you to write `Foo=new FooDerivedWhite()`

Comment: Just for more info, here is a gist https://gist.github.com/rgomez90/17ec21a1a371be6d78a53a4072938f7f  with my exact problem.

Comment: @Lee I mean, if I have something like `SomeMethod(T obj)` I can't declare `T` as covariant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to deal with this, but the most straightforward is probably to make your "other class" also have a generic type parameter that describes what kind of cheese it operates on. Then all the types can be statically correct.

```
public abstract class Cheese { }

public class BlueCheese : Cheese { }

public abstract class CheeseTool<T> where T:Cheese { }

public class BlueCheeseTool : CheeseTool<BlueCheese> { }

public class CheeseEater<T> where T : Cheese {
    public T Cheese;
    public CheeseTool<T> Tool;
}
```

Then all typing is statically correct:

```
CheeseEater<BlueCheese> eater = new CheeseEater<BlueCheese>();
eater.Cheese = new BlueCheese();
eater.Tool = new BlueCheeseTool();
```

More complicated solutions might involve explicit casts and type factories, but simplest is best if it does the job.